# powerpoint slide master mode: snap placeholder to object / other placeholder

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

I would like to design a more complicated powerpoint template with a number of objects and placeholder text boxes. I would like to have the objects and placeholders aligned with respect to each other. In the normal slide mode, I can use the snap to object function to perform this task. However, for some reason, this feature does not seem to be available in slide master mode.

Is there any way to activate this feature?

Thank you for your support.

Comment: Not sure what to suggest.  It works here (PPT 2010/32-bit, Win7/64).  Snap-to-grid interferes with it, so you'd want to turn that off when you turn snap-to-object on.

Comment: To clarify: I can snap objects to objects, even in slide master mode. But I can snap neither objects to placeholders (or vice versa), nor placeholders to placeholders. Placeholders don't snap to anything, not to grid and not to other objects. Turning "snap to grid" off does not help.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info.  I checked again and find that (same system again) shapes do snap to placeholders.  I've checked with rectangles and freeforms; both snap to the usual text placeholders and also e.g. footer placeholders.  What version of PPT do you use?